# R, Caret Predict(), and errors

Tags: r, prediction

So I've been playing around with/testing out a few ideas. I just wasn't sure though if there is a simple command you can use to have caret like send you back a list (or data.frame) of all the errors on your predict() 'ion'?

Or do you have to manually parse the list ?